# What does "I can see it in the head" mean?

Tags: expressions, idioms

In a book called "What the Dog Saw: And Other Adventures"(https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=6do2AQAAQBAJ&pg=PT77),  an exchange between a dog trainer and the dog's ower takes place as below.

...
"What about the bites?"
"**I can see it in the head**.  She gives me that look."
"She's reminding you who rules the roost."

I have trouble understanding the part "I can see it in the head".
Is it an idiomatic expression?
(Please see the link above if you need more context.)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not idiomatic. They're looking at a dog, and the person knows something just by looking at the dog. They "can see [the fact that the dog will bite] in the [appearance of] the [dog's] head." We're supposed to understand that the speaker is an expert on dogs so can easily discern things like this.

Comment: A more idiomatic expression would be 'I can see it in it's eyes'